# Dax gives me 2 drastically different answers when I use Date Add

Tags: time, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, dateadd

When I use

```
PY Apps = CALCULATE([CY Apps],DATEADD('Transaction Date'[Date],-365,DAY))
```

I get the Total $4,704 (which is what I was expecting)

When I use

```
PY Apps = CALCULATE([CY Apps],DATEADD('Transaction Date'[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

I get $13,926

why such a massive difference? how can it work correctly when i'm lowering it by days and completely fly off the handle when its Years

My Date Table is just a Calendar

```
Transaction Date = CALENDAR(MIN(Query1[received_date]),max(Query1[received_date]))
```

my model is just 2 tables, one table that has a list of dates with their respective sales, and then the other table is my date table

[image]

Comment: Is your date table ["well-formed"](https://dax.guide/dateadd/)?

Comment: i dunno what that means? its just 2 simple tables one of them has a unique list of dates, the other does not, the individual rows in the matrix are fine but the grand totals are messed up

Comment: The link explains what I mean.

Comment: MUCH APPRECIATED, turns out it was a problem with my Date Table, because it did not have all of the days for the month it was screwing up, when I increased my date table to go years into the future it worked perfectly